# how to active new input elements to bind blur function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to active new input elements to bind blur function?

sometimes I bind some functions on the document ready , when blur , focus , click , mouseover or other actions it will doing something in js. but this bindings do not works for new added elements, how can I bind functions to new added elements?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" name="a" value="a" />
    <input type="text" name="b" value="b" />
</div>
<button onclick="live_blur()">live_blur</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('[name]').blur(function (){
            alert(this.value);
        })
    });

    function live_blur(){
        $('.box').append('<input type="text" name="c" value="c" />');
        // how to acitve new inputs when blur and alert value
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the event to the `document` using the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.  The first argument is the event, the second specifies the target to execute the event for and the final argument is the function to execute (event handler).

```
   $(document).on('blur', '[name]',function (){
        alert(this.value);
    });
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZWkEn/

Comment: it there any other way to do it . sometime I using others function like tooltip(), this can not using "on" or "live" to fire event

Comment: @mingfish_004 i think you are looking for jquery trigger function : http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1):

you need to add an event listener to the newly created element

```
var input = $('<input type="text" name="c" value="c" />'); // create new <input>

$(".box").append(input); // append to your destination

input.on("blur", function () {
    console.log(this.value);
}); // register event listener
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zvuc6/

Comment: i am interested in "register event listener", can you write down a complete demo code?

Comment: you can see the demo in the jsfiddle link i list above

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to you, initialize your tooltip() again, after dyn.adding new elements